# How to get product review summary data in magento2

Tags: magento2

I need to get Product review  summery in magento2 programtically 
how to get it ?

Answer (score 3):

in list page you can use

```
if ($block->getMode() == 'grid') {
        $viewMode = 'grid';
        $image = 'category_page_grid';
        $showDescription = false;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    } else {
        $viewMode = 'list';
        $image = 'category_page_list';
        $showDescription = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
    }

<?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType); ?>
```

And Product Detail page You can use

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View")->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::product/view/review.phtml")->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code .

```
    $productid=1226;
    $product=$this->_objectManager->create("Magento\Catalog\Model\Product")->load($productid);
    $RatingOb=$this->_objectManager->create("Magento\Review\Model\Review");
    $RatingOb=$this->_objectManager->get("Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory");
    $RatingOb->create()->getEntitySummary($product, 1);
    print_r($product->getRatingSummary());      
    print_r($product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary());
```